# SQL Oracle (using AND clause)

Tags: sql, oracle

when I use below code, I get the data of customers who ordered "Planned" or 'obsolete' products, but I want to get data of the customers who ordered both type, changing 'or' to 'and' does not work... please help

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.CUST_EMAIL
    ,ORDERS.ORDER_ID
    ,PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_NAME
    ,PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS
FROM PRODUCT_INFORMATION
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON ORDER_ITEMS.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'planned'
    OR PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'obsolete'
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS.CUST_EMAIL;
```

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: I am not getting any error I am getting blank data, but there shoule be few lines which I can see from data I got using or clause, I have also tried group by clause.. but not working

Comment: is there data from planned and obsolete ?

Comment: Yes it is there , for eg: Frederico.Romero@CURLEW.COM has ordered both type of product, I can see that , there are others as well... I am using OE schema...

Comment: just try `PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS IN ('planned','obsolete')` also see any case change is there because when started question you said "Planned" and in query it is "planned"

Comment: Pls check spelling of STATUS. In addition pls try to share screenshots of your table.

Comment: @AK47: please do **not** encourage the posting of screenshots for sample data. Example data should be posted as formatted text or even better as `INSERT` statements.

Comment: product status is all in small, and I have also tried where.. in (..,..) statement but it is also pulling the same thing, customers with these two type, but I want to pull the data where customers ordered both of these two type, and other should not come...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would go one step further and say that sample data (and table structures) should be provided via a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: @A.G provide sample data and table structure

Comment: if we don't have sample data we won't know why you aren't getting any results, as far as I can see the only problem with this query and your data could be that none of your data actually answers all these joins and the where clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree with your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want the following. If you want to get correct answer, rather than guesses, please provide a good representative set of sample data and your expected result based on that sample data.

First part of the query returns Customers that ordered `planned` products, second part of the query returns Customers that ordered `obsolete` products. `INTERSECT` operator returns only those that have ordered both `planned` and `obsolete` products.

You don't need explicit `DISTINCT` any more, because `INTERSECT` would do it anyway.
I've removed `PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS` from the list of returned columns, because with it the result set would be always empty.

I removed `ORDERS.ORDER_ID` and `PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_NAME` from result as well. I don't know what should be the correct query, but it is likely that `INTERSECT` should be done just on `CUSTOMER_ID` and then, once you get the list of IDs, you can join other tables to it fetching other related details if needed.

The performance of this method is beyond the scope of the question.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,customers.CUST_EMAIL
FROM
    PRODUCT_INFORMATION
    INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID
    INNER JOIN ORDERS ON ORDER_ITEMS.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'planned'

INTERSECT

SELECT
    CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,customers.CUST_EMAIL
FROM
    PRODUCT_INFORMATION
    INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID
    INNER JOIN ORDERS ON ORDER_ITEMS.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'obsolete'

ORDER BY CUST_EMAIL
```

Comment: I have already tried intersect but strange it does not retrieving the data, whereas MINUS is puling correct data (), it is very strange although...

Comment: My answer is a guess. If you want correct answer, rather than a guess, edit your question and show few rows of data for each of the four tables and what you'd like to see as a result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

without the script for you tables it's difficult to build a test case and a working query; i'll try with this step:

```
    select order_id from (
SELECT customers.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,sum(decode(PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS, 'obsolete', 1, 0)) obsolete
    ,sum(decode(PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS, 'planned', 1, 0)) planned
FROM PRODUCT_INFORMATION
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON ORDER_ITEMS.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'planned'
    OR PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_STATUS = 'obsolete'
    group by customers.CUSTOMER_ID)
where obsolete>1 and planned>1
```

This query should return all the customer id that have items in orders with both the product status (the different product status may be in different orders), if you want to retrieve orders that have products with both status you must change the query removing customer.customer_id and adding orders.order_id. If you provide some script with sample data we can provide a better answer

Comment: Well  let me give one sample data and my expected answer, I am making it more simple with 2 tables only, but I actually have 4 tables in schema.

Table 1:
Cust  –  Order
A - 12
B - 13
A - 13
C - 12
D - 12
B - 12

Table 2: 
Order - Product
12 – planned
13 – obsolete 
14 – other 

Now: I wanted the expected data like below (planned & obsolete)
Expected data
Cust - product
A – 12
A – 13
B – 12
B – 13

But with ‘OR’ all A, B, C, D is coming and with ‘AND’ nothing is coming